# Не работает ajax в wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

Не могу понять в чем проблема. На самом сайте в обработчике нажатия на кнопку выполняю этот код:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'ajax_order'
            },
            success: function(res) {
                alert(123);
                console.log(res);
                console.log('успех');
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
              alert("Error: "+errorThrown+" , Please try again");   
            }
        });
```

в functions.php в самый низ добавляю:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_order', 'ajax_form' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_order', 'ajax_form' );

function ajax_form(){
    echo '123';
    die;
}
```

Если написать напрямую в браузере

> [http://[домен]/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=ajax_order](http://[%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD]/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=ajax_order)

то выдает результат, выходит ошибка в js, но где?

PS Jquery 2.1.1 подключается перед обработчиком нажатия на кнопку

Comment: Что в консоли при отправке аякса появляется?

Comment: ошибки консоли смотреть нужно. скорее всего, путь к обработчику Аякса неправильный